# Will adding code as library increase the size of the App

Tags: java, android, class, libraries

I have an Android App named A. 
I create a new copy B with the same functionality but different package name. 
The difference between both the apps will be usage of different AD Network.

- I divide my Code into different libraries and upload them to online
  repository, so that I can simply change the code in both the app by
  simply changing a single line in both the apps Gradel file.
- Instead of manually changing the code for both the apps.

> For Eg-
>
> A has three features X,Y,Z
>
> B has two features X,Y.

Now if there is some  issue in X feature I will have to change the code for X in both A and B but if I plan to divide them into library I will have to change the code only once and update the A and B apps with the new libraries.

But will using this kind of setup will it increase the size of the app, OR will it be the same as if I use the code manually.

EDIT: Is there any other dis-advantage for adding code as library?

Comment: Hard to tell,but yes in general adding libraries to app increase the size of the app ofcourse, but in your case it's definitly a good apraoch in favour of code refactoring, and i don't see any inconveniences of using a library

Comment: @B.M Thank you very much for the answer. But can you please tell the comparative ratio of increase in the size.

Comment: If it helps, AppCompat support library increase the size of the app by almost 1M ,but it contains a lot of drawables and ressources,

Comment: @B.M Thanks. But is it possible that I add the AppCmpact library in my main app only and don't add it to the library? Also can you please post an answer for me to accept.

Comment: Yes it's actually better if you add it on the main app, since you won't need it on your library

Comment: @B.M Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell,but yes in general adding libraries to app increase the size of the app ofcourse, but in your case it's definitly a good apraoch in favour of code refactoring, and i don't see any inconveniences of using a library